# WordPress Theme Customizer toolbar CSS

Tags: wordpress, admin

How can I update the default WordPress Theme Customizer toolbar CSS so that I could for example change the text color from the default black.

The default hook to add admin CSS does not seem to work here `add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_css');`

So for example the `#theme-description`  id, could be change to another color but how?!

*I actually want to add some CSS to a custom option but rather than pasting lots of confusing code I am trying to keep the question simple, so If I can change the CSS for this then I can create CSS for what I need.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try the **customize_controls_print_styles** hook I think:

```
function theme_customizer_css() { ?>
    <style>
       // Custom Styles in here
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_styles', 'theme_customizer_css' );
```